# A reference to a theorem about L1-bounded Martingales

Tags: analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, martingales, borel-measures

I'm auditing a course called "Topics in Analysis", and in class we mentioned a theorem that didn't make sense to me. I don't fully remember how it goes, but it was something like:

> Theorem (half-remembered, probably not the correct formulation): The limit of an $L^1$-bounded Martingale can be uniquely decomposed into the sum of three pieces:
>
> 1. an $L^1$ function
> 2. a countable collection of Dirac masses
> 3. a continuous Borel measure

The reason this confused me was, first of all, how are we adding functions and measures together? Are we implicitly converting functions to measures so that they have the same type? And if we are, why is category 1 disjoint from category 3? (I say they must be disjoint because otherwise we break uniqueness by subtracting f from the first piece of the decomposition and adding back f, or at least its measure version, into the third piece.)

So I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could either explain this to me, or provide me with a reference so I could read about this, because I've clearly misunderstood *something* here.

(I tried asking the teacher about it after class, but he kept on just stating that 1 and 3 are disjoint and repeating the statement of the theorem, without answering why or how or addressing my question. It was very frustrating)

EDIT: Oh, I should also say that I tried Googling this and couldn't find anything.

Comment: (In fairness, I did come into the course partway through, but I had thought last class that I had managed to understand what a Martingale is through context. After this class, I am no longer so sure)

Comment: It’s not a result I’m familiar with but it does sound somewhat close to the Lebesgue decomposition theorem for measures and the Doob and Doob-Meyer decompositions for (certain) discrete and continuous time processes. But all of these say quite different things than what is written here. Is there a textbook for the class?

Comment: @NapD.Lover I'm not sure. (I'm not really an official member of the class, I just asked if I could sit in last week and this week and the professor said yes.) Part of what's making looking this up difficult is that, in class, "Martingale" meant a certain sequence of functions on [0,1], but online it seems to mean a sequence of random variables.

Comment: Well, random variables are just functions $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ of the sample space (which is often ignored on purpose in probability theory after some point) and we could very well choose to work in the probability space $([0,1], \mathscr{B}[0,1], dx)$ with the Borel sigma algebra and Lebesgue measure. So this may just be a specialized case? Hard to tell.

Comment: @NapD.Lover After asking people elsewhere on the internet, I have a possible answer: in #3, it's supposed to be a continuous _singular_ Borel measure. As far as I can tell, the theorem (particularly the uniqueness) is false if the word "singular" is left out, but putting it in resolves all of my confusions. (I sent my professor an email asking if that was what he meant to write. If it actually is the case that he just left a word out, I am baffled how my repeated requests for clarification didn't get him to notice the error.)